# Go parser not detecting Doc comments on struct type

Tags: parsing, go, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to read the assocated Doc comments on a struct type using Go’s [parser](http://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) and [ast](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/) packages. In this example, the code simply uses itself as the source.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
)

// FirstType docs
type FirstType struct {
    // FirstMember docs
    FirstMember string
}

// SecondType docs
type SecondType struct {
    // SecondMember docs
    SecondMember string
}

// Main docs
func main() {
    fset := token.NewFileSet() // positions are relative to fset

    d, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, "./", nil, parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for _, f := range d {
        ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
            switch x := n.(type) {
            case *ast.FuncDecl:
                fmt.Printf("%s:\tFuncDecl %s\t%s\n", fset.Position(n.Pos()), x.Name, x.Doc)
            case *ast.TypeSpec:
                fmt.Printf("%s:\tTypeSpec %s\t%s\n", fset.Position(n.Pos()), x.Name, x.Doc)
            case *ast.Field:
                fmt.Printf("%s:\tField %s\t%s\n", fset.Position(n.Pos()), x.Names, x.Doc)
            }

            return true
        })
    }
}
```

The comment docs for the func and fields are output no problem, but for some reason the ‘FirstType docs’ and ‘SecondType docs’ are nowhere to be found. What am I missing? Go version is 1.1.2.

(To run the above, save it into a main.go file, and `go run main.go`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the `go/doc` package to extract documentation from the ast:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/doc"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
)

// FirstType docs
type FirstType struct {
    // FirstMember docs
    FirstMember string
}

// SecondType docs
type SecondType struct {
    // SecondMember docs
    SecondMember string
}

// Main docs
func main() {
    fset := token.NewFileSet() // positions are relative to fset

    d, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, "./", nil, parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for k, f := range d {
        fmt.Println("package", k)
        p := doc.New(f, "./", 0)

        for _, t := range p.Types {
            fmt.Println("  type", t.Name)
            fmt.Println("    docs:", t.Doc)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although go/doc is a solution this still doesn't answer why go/ast doesn't provide comments/doc on type (e.g. on `TypeSpec`)

Answer (score 24):

#### Great question!

Looking at the source code of `go/doc`, we can see that it has to deal with this same case in `readType` function. There, it says:

```
324     func (r *reader) readType(decl *ast.GenDecl, spec *ast.TypeSpec) {
...
334     // compute documentation
335     doc := spec.Doc
336     spec.Doc = nil // doc consumed - remove from AST
337     if doc == nil {
338         // no doc associated with the spec, use the declaration doc, if any
339         doc = decl.Doc
340     }
...
```

Notice in particular how it needs to deal with the case where the AST does not have a doc attached to the TypeSpec. To do this, it falls back on the `GenDecl`. This gives us a clue as to how we might use the AST directly to parse doc comments for structs. Adapting the for loop in the question code to add a case for `*ast.GenDecl`:

```
for _, f := range d {
    ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
        switch x := n.(type) {
        case *ast.FuncDecl:
            fmt.Printf("%s:\tFuncDecl %s\t%s\n", fset.Position(n.Pos()), x.Name, x.Doc.Text())
        case *ast.TypeSpec:
            fmt.Printf("%s:\tTypeSpec %s\t%s\n", fset.Position(n.Pos()), x.Name, x.Doc.Text())
        case *ast.Field:
            fmt.Printf("%s:\tField %s\t%s\n", fset.Position(n.Pos()), x.Names, x.Doc.Text())
        case *ast.GenDecl:
            fmt.Printf("%s:\tGenDecl %s\n", fset.Position(n.Pos()), x.Doc.Text())
        }

        return true
    })
}
```

Running this gives us:

```
main.go:3:1:    GenDecl %!s(*ast.CommentGroup=<nil>)
main.go:11:1:   GenDecl &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{69 // FirstType docs})]}
main.go:11:6:   TypeSpec FirstType  %!s(*ast.CommentGroup=<nil>)
main.go:13:2:   Field [FirstMember] &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{112 // FirstMember docs})]}
main.go:17:1:   GenDecl &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{155 // SecondType docs})]}
main.go:17:6:   TypeSpec SecondType %!s(*ast.CommentGroup=<nil>)
main.go:19:2:   Field [SecondMember]    &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{200 // SecondMember docs})]}
main.go:23:1:   FuncDecl main   &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{245 // Main docs})]}
main.go:33:23:  Field [n]   %!s(*ast.CommentGroup=<nil>)
main.go:33:35:  Field []    %!s(*ast.CommentGroup=<nil>)
```

#### And, hey!

We've printed out the long-lost `FirstType docs` and `SecondType docs`! But this is unsatisfactory. Why is the doc not attached to the `TypeSpec`? The `go/doc/reader.go` file goes to extraordinary lengths to circumvent this issue, actually generating a fake `GenDecl` and passing it to the `readType` function mentioned earlier, if there is no documentation associated with the struct declaration!

```
   503  fake := &ast.GenDecl{
   504   Doc: d.Doc,
   505   // don't use the existing TokPos because it
   506   // will lead to the wrong selection range for
   507   // the fake declaration if there are more
   508   // than one type in the group (this affects
   509   // src/cmd/godoc/godoc.go's posLink_urlFunc)
   510   TokPos: s.Pos(),
   511   Tok:    token.TYPE,
   512   Specs:  []ast.Spec{s},
   513  }
```

#### But why all this?

Imagine we changed the type definitions from code in the question slightly (defining structs like this is not common, but still valid Go):

```
// This documents FirstType and SecondType together
type (
    // FirstType docs
    FirstType struct {
        // FirstMember docs
        FirstMember string
    }

    // SecondType docs
    SecondType struct {
        // SecondMember docs
        SecondMember string
    }
)
```

Run the code (including the case for `ast.GenDecl`) and we get:

```
main.go:3:1:    GenDecl %!s(*ast.CommentGroup=<nil>)
main.go:11:1:   GenDecl &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{69 // This documents FirstType and SecondType together})]}
main.go:13:2:   TypeSpec FirstType  &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{129 // FirstType docs})]}
main.go:15:3:   Field [FirstMember] &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{169 // FirstMember docs})]}
main.go:19:2:   TypeSpec SecondType &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{215 // SecondType docs})]}
main.go:21:3:   Field [SecondMember]    &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{257 // SecondMember docs})]}
main.go:26:1:   FuncDecl main   &{[%!s(*ast.Comment=&{306 // Main docs})]}
main.go:36:23:  Field [n]   %!s(*ast.CommentGroup=<nil>)
main.go:36:35:  Field []    %!s(*ast.CommentGroup=<nil>)
```

#### That's right

Now the struct type definitions have their docs, and the `GenDecl` has its own documentation, too. In the first case, posted in the question, the doc was attached to `GenDecl`, since the AST sees the individual struct type definitions of "contractions" of the parenthesized-version of type definitions, and wants to handle all definitions the same, whether they are grouped or not. The same thing would happen with variable definitions, as in:

```
// some general docs
var (
    // v docs
    v int

    // v2 docs
    v2 string
)
```

So if you wish to parse comments with pure AST, you need to be aware that this is how it works. But the preferred method, as @mjibson suggested, is to use `go/doc`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

parse all structs with comment // typescript:interface

```
func TestStructDoc(t *testing.T) {
err := filepath.Walk(".",
    func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            fmt.Println(path, info.Size())
            fset := token.NewFileSet()
            d, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, path, nil, parser.ParseComments)
            if err != nil {
                t.Fatal(err)

            }

            for k, f := range d {
                fmt.Println("package", k)
                p := doc.New(f, "./", 0)

                for _, t := range p.Types {
                    fmt.Println("  type", t.Name)
                    fmt.Println("    docs:", t.Doc)
                    if strings.HasPrefix(t.Doc, "typescript:interface") {

                        for _, spec := range t.Decl.Specs {
                            switch spec.(type) {
                            case *ast.TypeSpec:
                                typeSpec := spec.(*ast.TypeSpec)

                                fmt.Printf("Struct: name=%s\n", typeSpec.Name.Name)

                                switch typeSpec.Type.(type) {
                                case *ast.StructType:
                                    structType := typeSpec.Type.(*ast.StructType)
                                    for _, field := range structType.Fields.List {
                                        i := field.Type.(*ast.Ident)
                                        fieldType := i.Name

                                        for _, name := range field.Names {
                                            fmt.Printf("\tField: name=%s type=%s\n", name.Name, fieldType)
                                        }

                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    })
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't your problem, but for anyone else searching and wondering why their code isn't parsing comments properly:

Make sure you remember to pass the `parser.ParseComments` flag!!!